# How do I get the Item Type from CollectionView in .net

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Say I have an `CollectionView`, how I get the Item Type?

```cs
public Type GetItemType()
{

    CollectionView items = DataGrid.Items;
    Type itemType = items.GetType // ...;

    return itemType;
}
```

Comment: you can do it using a foreach loop have you tried that..

Comment: yes, but the collectiom may be empty.

Comment: so ...then do a check on the Collection to check if Count > 0

Comment: the collection being empty shouldn't matter (from the for each's perspective), unless it's null, and you can check for that.

Comment: for example `foreach(var item in items)
{
 if(item is string)` etc...

Comment: I need to know the item type even if the collection is empty.

Comment: if your collection is no generic, then you have no way of knowing what `Type` of objects to store in it as it could have many objects of different types. Anything else would be a happenstance depending on your code

Comment: @Luiso it is possible

Comment: @AshkanSirous how could you be sure (with out genericity) that all objects have the same concrete type? Even if in the collection all objects have a common base type (other than object) the concrete types could very well be different since nothing is done in compile time to ensure type uniqueness. Maybe I am missing something though, could you please tell me how'd you get the `Type` in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have items inside your list. if you have a collectionview, you can just take its source collection and using that you can get type of its items

```
  var myEnumarator= myCollectionView.SourceCollection.GetEnumerator();
  var mytype = myEnumarator.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```